# two scrolls get triggered at once

Tags: jquery, mcustomscrollbar

I've currently been using jQuery Custom Scrollbar on a project.
I have a main div with a scrollbar and another small div with a scrollbar inside the main div. And whenever I scroll the small div it triggers the main div to scroll when the scrollbar meets the end of the content.
How do I prevent the main div from being scrolled when I scroll the small div?

Cheers.

Comment: show us your html,css,js to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without seeing the code. Usually, it is possible to stop events from bubbling up by using `e.stopPropagation();`. For example,

```
$('#someDiv').on('scroll', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // rest of Scrollbar code
});
```

If you don't have access to, or prefer not to modify, the `scroll` event in the source code for the scrollbar, you'll need to track the event "end of scroll" for the small div and trigger a `e.preventDefault()` or `e.stopPropagation();`. Your code would be helpful for a more precise answer.